# history missing in components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, history

I just now observed that some of my component is having history and some do not have it. 
My component is `comp1, comp2, comp3`

comp1 is parent of comp2, comp2 is parent of comp3

```
comp1
|____comp2
     |_____comp3
```

Given all are stateful components. And access to `comp1` is through routing.

My observations says that those component who are connected through routers directly have only the `this.props.history` available.

> Q. Can any one throw some light here on this fact?
>
> Q. Can we access history on remaining components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components given to the `component` prop of a `Route` component will be given the [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props). If you want a component deeper down in your app to have access to them as well, you can use the [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC.

**Example**

```
class Component3 extends React.Component {
  render () {
    console.log(this.props.history);

    return <h3> Test </h3>;
  }
}

export default withRouter(Component3);
```

Comment: you mean if I pass my Component in withRouter, that HOC will return me a component that has history and some more key value pairs attached to it

Comment: @Ladoo That's right. It will give you the history object’s properties and the closest `<Route>`'s match

Comment: thanx.. this is a new thing I learnt.. thanx for links too. But I used 'react-router-dom' for this